# How to show message once per login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-variables, session-cookies

How would you construct your controller or even in views, a way to show an error message or welcome message only once per user session or per user login. I currently have this;

```
    <% if session[:user_id] = current_user.id && signed_in? %>
    <% if @check_password_warning.present? %>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="AccountModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AccountModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <center><%= @check_password_warning %></center>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

but that shows my password warning each time a user refreshes the page, I've tried changing the `session[:user_id] = current_user.id` to `session[:new_session] = true` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`=` assignment operator in `ruby`

```
=> a = 1
=> 1
=> a == 1
=> true
```

try this

```
if session[:user_id] == current_user.id && signed_in?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flash` hash. This lets you optionally show messages on your page.

[The Flash | Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)